# Is the interval $\pmb [0, 1)$ homeomorphic to the unit circle if we consider the circle as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$ with the lower limit topology?

Tags: general-topology

If not, why not?

I have included the page of Munkres which describes why $\mathbb [0, 1)$ is not homeomorphic to the unit circle $\mathbf S$ where $\mathbf S$ is considered a subspace of $\mathbb R$$^2$ with the usual topology. We define a function $\mathbf F:$ $\mathbf [0, 1)$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbf S$ defined by $\mathbb f(t) = (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$. The reason $\mathbf F$ is not a homeomorphism is because the image under $\mathbf f$ of the open set $\mathbf U = [0, \frac{1}{4})$ is not open in $\mathbf S$, for the point $\mathit p = f(0)$ lies in no open set $\mathbf V$ of $\mathbb R$$^2$ such that $\mathbf V \cap S$ $\subset$ $\mathbf f(U)$

I have also included a picture I made that describes my question, when considering  $\mathbf S$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R_\ell^2$ where $\mathbb R_\ell^2$  is $\mathbb R^2$ with the lower limit topology. The red semi circle I drew on the right looks exactly like the $\mathbf f(U)$ we see in the page of Munkres.

[image: Unit circle when considered as a subspace of R^2 with the usual topology]

[image: Unit circle when considered as a subspace of R^2 with the lower limit topology]

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry I'm not sure, I've only started self studying topology recently

Comment: Btw. the fact that the one specic map $t\mapsto(\cos2\pi t,\sin 2\pi t)$ fails to be a homeomorphism is not enough to prove that interval and (standard) circle are not homeomorphic

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen How can I prove that two spaces are not homeomorphic?

Comment: If you know that compactness is a topological invariant, just observe that the circle is compact and the interval is not.

Comment: I see, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that $V \cap S$ is open in $\mathbb{R}_\ell^2$, but the problem is you've added *far* too many open sets when you extended topologies from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}_\ell^2$.

In particular, every point $\{x\} \subset V\cap S$ is open in $S$ since it's the bottom left corner of a basic open set that intersects $S$ only at $\{x\}$.  This is far from the topology of $[0,1)$ (which in particular has no open points and is connected).

Comment: You correctly removed "has no infinite discrete subspace" and replaced it with "connected". Alternatively, you could have changed it to "has non *uncountable* discrete subspace" or "has a countable dense suspace" -- there are of course many topological properties that can distinguish the two spaces

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand the meaning/implications of adding too many open sets, we haven't gotten to the section on connected sets yet. Are there any topologies/any way for that mapping F to be a homeomorphism between [0, 1) and the unit circle? Maybe if we do $\mathbb R$ x $\mathbb R$$\ell$?

Comment: @ILoveMath333 As far as I know, not in any interesting way.  We can of course just add additional open neighborhoods of $(1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, but this seems fairly artificial to me.

Comment: By the way, if you don't know about connectedness, just ignore that part.  No point of $[0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open.  That's really all I need here.  Since $F$ is bijective, $F^{-1}(\{x\})$ is a point in $[0,1)$ which is also open since $F$ is continuous and $\{x\}$ is open.  However, there is no point of $[0,1)$ which is open.

Comment: I'll just add one related property that Hagen didn't mention: "has no infinite closed discrete subspace".

Comment: @Adayah $\left\{1-\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}\right\}$

Comment: Why did I think the space was $[0, 1]$? Nevermind.